# Can you create a GD image in PHP from an image in memory?

Tags: php, gd

I need the a function like imagecreatefrompng(), but I want to pass in the image directly (as opposed to the filename). Is this possible?

Note: I need this because the image is coming from a blob in a database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`imagecreatefromstring()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php)

It should detect it is a `png` from the image header and return an image resource.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use imagecreatefromstring()

ttp://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php